# Sed not working with find command

Tags: sed

I'm trying to run this sed script on all the files in a directory:

sed.s:

```
/<constants>/a\
<const type="profElem" name="mission_description" value="NCEP and NCAR Reanalysis Monthly Means and Other Derived Variables"/>
```

but whenever I run:

```
find . -exec sed -f sed.s -i {} \;
```

I get the error:

```
sed: -i may not be used with stdin
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Would be interesting to see the list of files. Could you post the result of `find . -exec echo {} \;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your version of `sed` requires you to pass an extension for backups to the `-i` option.  If you feel pretty confident in your command you could try to give it a zero-length extension like so:

```
find . -exec sed -f sed.s -i '' {} \;
```